# I have SSD and HDD on my laptop and I want to encrypt my HDD only?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, encryption

I have SSD and HDD on my laptop and I want to encrypt my HDD only ? My os is installed on SSD . So how could I encrypt my HDD with veracrypt without losing data. My HDD also has 2 partitions . I want to encrypt both partitions .or you could say full HDD which has 2 logical drives . Please advice. Don't want to loose any data and how to hide my partitions or dismount my partitions from windows 10 so no one can see it. I could mount them when I need to add anything

Comment: While installing Veracrypt it will allow you to choose which drive(s) you want to encrypt. Just follow the instructions.

Comment: But can I hide them by dismounting them from veracrypt so no one could even see them and when need to use it then just mount back . Is it possible

Comment: Yes that is possible. https://www.veracrypt.fr/code/VeraCrypt/plain/src/Release/Setup%20Files/VeraCrypt%20User%20Guide.pdf?id=e6ebc63c665dfd38802f63ad8882f573e66cd208

Comment: @Guest - Anyone with physical access to your machine can just mount them, unless your talking about encrypting them, and then hiding them. You should clarify what your question actually is by editing it